# Canadian gifting a biological parent living in and citizen of the US

Tags: united-states, taxes, gift-tax

As a Canadian Citizen I have given (gifted) in excess of 100K US to my adult child (US Citizen) living in the US with no tax implications other than him filling out the proper form to acknowledge it. Can I do the same thing for a US Citizen parent living in the US?